# Build issues with libzbar based Qt application

Tags: c++, linux, qt, cross-compiling, zbar

I am using libzbarQT (libzbarQT.so) in my QT code.I am facing an error while building the code saying "undefined reference to QWidget::qwsEvent(QWSEvent *event)".I am not using this function in my QT code.I want to know which function is internally calling this function so that I can tweak the library a bit.
Any suggestions please..

Thanks in advance for any help.

PS: I am crosscompiling my code using arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ toolchain with LTIB.
To solve error '/usr/lib/libzbarqt.so: undefined reference to `QX11Info::display()', I have build Qt with X11.Now I am getting error:libzbarqt.so: undefined reference to`QWidget::qwsEvent(QWSEvent*)' error.

Comment: Show your code and the project file. I assume it is Qt 4?

Comment: Yes it is Qt 4.I am pasting my pro file..

Comment: QT+= core gui
INCLUDEPATH += /home/sainath/ltib/ltib/rootfs/usr/include/
#greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = NewDemo
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

LIBS += -L/home/sainath/ltib/ltib/rootfs/usr/lib/
LIBS += -lQtGui -lQtCore -ljpeg -lv4l2 -lSM -lICE -lX11 -lv4lconvert -lxcb-xlib -lXau -lxcb
LIBS += -lzbar
LIBS += -lzbarqt

Comment: Uh, not in the comment! Here is the paste now anyway: http://pastebin.kde.org/patab2xho

Comment: To solve error '/usr/lib/libzbarqt.so: undefined reference to `QX11Info::display()', I have build Qt with X11.Now I am getting error:libzbarqt.so: undefined reference to `QWidget::qwsEvent(QWSEvent*)' error.

Comment: Which qt version exactly are you using? Have you checked with either "nm -a" or "objdump" if you have the required symbol in your qt library? It will not work without a build with symbols though.

Comment: I am using Qt4.6.0. I have checked with nm -a libqtgui.so but i didn't find this symbol.

Comment: That means you are using an incompatible Qt build for your libzbarqt version. You either need to get one which complies with that, or you need to patch the symbol usage out, but that may be lotta work. You could also try to grab a different version of libzbarqt.

Comment: I am using latest version of libzbarqt. It recommends to use Qt Version greater than 4. Can you please explain what is meant by patching the symbol usage.

Comment: I am not sure what explanation that needs. You need to grab a qt version having that symbol, or you need to modify the library built not to use that symbol.

Comment: I have checked for this function qwsEvent() in libzbar source code. I could not found it. Can we find whether this function is being used in other libraries on which libzbarqt.so depends upon.

Comment: It is possible that the zbar dynamic library you have was built against the embedded qt version rather than the desktop Linux. Are you sure you did not mix up the embedded vs. desktop installation? qws* was only available on embedded, hence if it is required, you need the embedded installation of Qt, not the desktop. They were separate.

Comment: Is the issue resolved now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you could make sure that the symbols are present in the library unless it is built without symbols. I usually use the `nm -a` and `objdump` utilities for that operation.

More to the point: it seems that the zbar dynamic library that you have was built against the embedded version of Qt rather than the desktop Linux.

It is an unfortunate issue that both versions have the same dynamic library file names, so things like `ldd` cannot be much of help.

You will need to make sure to use exactly the same version of Qt installation that the library was built against. This means, if you use the desktop Linux installation for this, it will not work.